# Dinamizar Ajax Autocomplete Jquery com dados de json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Quero fazer sugestões de forma dinâmica com esta **[API](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)**.

### Como dinamizar o arquivo de sugestões listando dados do banco mysql?

> Download da DEMO:
>   https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

O arquivo `countries.js` é o que contém o dicionário de sugestões, porém manualmente, desejo algo dinâmico com as sugestões cadastradas no banco sendo listadas nele.

## countries.js

```
    var countries = {
    "AD": "Andorra",
    "AE": "United Arab Emirates",
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "AI": "Anguilla",
    "AL": "Albania",
    "AM": "Armenia",
    "WK": "Wake Island",
    "WS": "Samoa",
    "YD": "People's Democratic Republic of Yemen",
    "YE": "Yemen",
    "YT": "Mayotte",
    "ZA": "South Africa",
    "ZM": "Zambia",
    "ZW": "Zimbabwe",
    "ZZ": "Unknown or Invalid Region"
}
```

#### Instruções do manual da API

**Formato resposta**
A Resposta do servidor deve ser JSON formatado seguinte objeto JavaScript:

```
{
    // Query is not required as of version 1.2.5
    "query": "Unit",
    "suggestions": [
        { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
        { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
        { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
    ]
}
```

Os dados podem ser qualquer valor ou objeto. Objeto de dados é passado para `formatResults function` e `onSelect callback`. Alternativamente, se não houver dados você pode fornecer apenas uma matriz de cadeia para sugestões, como:

```
{
    "query": "Unit",
    "suggestions": ["United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Como no exemplo do site que foi mencionado, você deve adicinar uma URL no atributo `serviceUrl` no objeto de configuração do componente, algo como .

Esta URL deve apontar para um página do lado do servidor que retorna um JSON no formato desejado. Você consegue setar isso modificando os headers da requisição. Em PHP, você ainda pode serializar o objeto em json diretamente, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
<?PHP
$data = /** Objeto a serializar **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Nesta página você deve usar o formato que já conhece para acessar a base de dados e etc.

Comment: Olá @vkrausser boa noite e obrigado pela atenção, você poderia postar um exemplo para que eu possa entender um pouco melhor? tks